# LINQ to objects changing the display column

Tags: linq, object

hope some can help -

my webservice returns an object with certain fields
i use ling to object to filer the display an dthen bind the annonymous type to the grid.
is there a away to do a similar select as to change the display of the grid column?

for example

```
        Dim wsr As wsTest.Service = New wsTest.Service

        Dim objs() As wsTest.Person

        objs = wsr.GetPersons


        Dim q = From a In objs _
                Select a.Manifest, a.Id

        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = q.ToArray
```

i want to change it so that i get "select a.manifest as 'newID', a.id as 'Identifier'

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
Dim q = From a In objs _
        Select newId = a.Manifest, identifier = a.Id
```